# Debugging properties in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have a few properties that I'm using in some sample code I'm playing with. Notably the "tag" property of the UIView class. Now I set this property, and if I `NSLog` it, or setup control statements based on the value of tag, I can see that the value I set is there, and being acted upon as expected.

However, if I hover the mouse over the .tag to see which tag value is there, I get nothing at all from Xcode. No pop up showing the value. So then I go to the auto/local/all window and I try to "Add Expression..." (seems that's the only way to setup a traditional "watch" variable, if there is another way, please let me know). Anyhow so I put my object.tag into the "watch" window and it's blank. No value. It isn't zero it's just nothing, as if it didn't exist.

Of course if I hover the mouse over the "object" part of "object.tag" then I get a pop up for the object with the disclosure triangle, which I expand, then I go looking for "_tag" (which appears to be the underlying instance variable).

So what is so difficult about this? Why isn't the tag property viewable during debug by simply hovering over it? Is this something to do with properties in Xcode dev?

I'm running Xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tag` property, as any other Objective-C property, is a syntactic sugar. In fact, properties are implemented as accessor methods, which, in turn, are translated to `objc_msgSend()` function calls. This machinery is nothing like accessing a struct field.

The debugger can show any field in a struct basically because it doesn't require any special knowledge and doesn't have any consequences. Only the struct definition is needed. Getting the value of an Objective-C property, on the other hand, requires executing code in the process context. You can do that manually in the debugger console, but the debugger just won't do this automatically.

I think this is still theoretically possible *in isolated cases*, but incredibly hard. Consider a case where executing an accessor method changes the object's internal state. For example, calling `-[UIViewController view]` (accessing its `view` property) results in loading the view. There may also be delegate methods called, etc. In such cases hovering the mouse over the property in IDE would alter the execution state of the process and thus make debugging itself a joke.

Comment: I was aware that the property is syntactic sugar, but I didn't take that to the conclusion you pointed out. Thanks for clearing it up. At least I won't keep looking for something that doesn't exist.

On a related note, how do you generally go about discovering the name that is wrapped by the property? For instance, I simply stumbled upon _tag being the underlying variable the property tag was wrapping. I hate to assume that what I might be looking for just has a prepended underscore, so is there an easy way to discover this? I check the docs and didn't see anything.

Comment: In general, there is no correlation between a property and an ivar because properties may be "dynamic", i.e. returning a value calculated on the fly. I never look at ivar values unless it's my class and I know who is who. For example, some Apple's classes contain deprecated ivars, ivars with no obvious purpose, obfuscated and even hidden ivars (most often, an object of a private class). In general, while debugging, it makes sense to concentrate on _your own code_'s behavior, the code you have unlimited access to.

Comment: I see, so then if I'm tracking something like the UIView.tag (something from another class) my only real option then if debugging a problem related to such a "black box" property is to manually print it in the Output window?

Comment: Yes. It's a pain, I know. In these circumstances I use `NSLog()` a lot. By the way, `po aView` in the debugger console also prints out `aView`'s tag, if set.